# "Content width" of a web document

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, firefox

On most browsers, and on a typical webpage (say, bbc.com), if you resize the document, there is a precise width at which the horizontal scrollbar appears. If window width is larger than this, the scrollbar isn't there. This seems to be the "intended" content width of the document. What I want to know is what is the html/javascript property that can give me this width.

Comment: You just set width:your width; to your #wrapper. And min-width:your width; to the body. Also to center your page add margin:0 auto; to your wrapper

Comment: It's neither html or Javascript it's [CSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascading_Style_Sheets) and the property your after is [width](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/width)

Answer (score 0):

The content width of a web document is fluid. The browser will always try to reflow items to fit into the window if possible. When it isn't possible, this is when you get scroll bars.

For example, if you have a page full of paragraph tags with text only, you will likely never see a scroll bar until the window size is smaller than the longest word. However, when you have an object with an absolute size (and `display: block`), this is when you will see scroll bars.

Any object in the page can have an absolute width, often in pixels or ems, and this width will dictate when scroll bars appear. It depends on the structure of the page but often you have a container with a fixed width (e.g. `width: 960px`) or a "fluid" container with a relative width plus `min-width` and `max-width` properties. How you set these CSS properties will dictate how the page behaves.

If you always use relative widths, it's possible to never see a scroll bar. This concept is the beginning of designing a responsive web page.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [A Tale of Two Viewports](http://www.quirksmode.org/mobile/viewports.html). You are probably looking for:

```
document.documentElement.offset[Width|Height]
document.documentElement.scroll[Width|Height]
document.documentElement.client[Width|Height]
```

The blog post I linked to above has more info.